# How To parse XML and JSON data in single Response in Android

Tags: android, xml, json

Can Any one help me to parse XML and JSON data response in Android.
From my web service i got following type of response.
i am bit confused as to how can i parse this data .
Due to low reputation i can't upload image of response.
help me to parse in android.
[here is link of response](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xqo46d978f2jk3/Selection_011.png?dl=0)

Comment: You don't have to upload an *image* of the response - it's text. Just include it in your question (indented, like code).

Comment: Parse xml first and pass the value as String from xml parsed data to json parser to explore the values.

Comment: i don't have any idea about XML parsing . i am work with JSON only.

Comment: can you send me any ref.  link or code please

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that's just XML *wrapping* JSON. So parse it as XML, then take the text content of the root element (the only element present) and then parse that as JSON.

Basically, just do one thing at a time and you'll be fine: treat the XML as "just XML" where you want the text content, and treat the JSON as "just JSON" - it's irrelevant that it was previously wrapped in XML.

(You might also want to see if there's anything you can do to make the web service just return plain JSON. There's no reason to wrap it in XML like this...)